# How can I insert a chart into a Google Docs document?

Tags: google-docs

I can make charts with the spreadsheet, but is there a way to insert the chart into a Docs document?  Is using a static image the best I can do?  Are there any online tools where I could copy the same series of numbers and have it do it for me?

Comment: A "duplicate" posted 5 years before the "original", must be a record.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/making_charts.html). Simply embed an image in your document, with it's src being a call to the chart API, like this:

[image]

(the URL in this case is: [https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&cht=p3&chl=Hello|World](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x100&chd=t:60,40&cht=p3&chl=Hello%7CWorld))

Comment: Unfortunately, `Image Charts` are deprecated, and Google could remove this functionality. (https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) Alternatively, you could embed a published chart from a Google Spreadsheet, which is explained in this question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/89977/how-can-i-embed-a-chart-from-a-google-spreadsheet-in-a-google-doc